# Laravel get user_id from others tables for store

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 4 tables :-

1. User

   - id
   - username
   - password
   - email
2. available_offers

   - id
   - date
   - time
   - from
   - to
3. requested_routes

   - id
   - user_id
   - available_offersID
4. rating_passengers

   - id
   - user_id
   - available_offersID
   - rating

Here what this system do :-

1. I have one page call my routes offered as driver

   - display date
   - display time
   - display from
   - display to
   - display passenger name
   - display rating given
   - radio button for rating
   - submit button
2. I[driver] can rate any passenger that booked me
3. The rate should be store in tables_rating_passengers

Here my controller :-

```
class routes_offeredController extends Controller
{
public function create()
{

    $passengers = requested_routes::with('available_offers', 'user')
                ->get();

    //return $passengers;

    return view ('routes_offered.show', compact('passengers'));
}

public function store()
{
    rating_passenger::create([

        'user_id' =>Auth::id(),
        'rating' => request('rating'),
        ]);

    return redirect('/');
}
}
```

Result if i return $passengers

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "available_offersID": 1,
  "created_at": null,
  "updated_at": null,
  "available_offers": {
     "id": 1,
     "date": "2017-08-08",
     "time": "14:11:15",
     "from": "Perlis",
     "to": "Kedah",
     "user_id": 3,
     "isBooked": 0,
     "created_at": null,
     "updated_at": null
  },
  "user": {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "safwan",
     "username": "safwan123",
     "email": "wan@gmail.com",
     "created_at": null,
     "updated_at": null
  }
]
```

My view

[image]

In my routes_offered view, i could display all data. I also already save data to tables rating_passenger. The only problem here is, I could not get id for available_offers[user_id for passenger] to save to database.

Comment: Is there any place in the view where the user choose the `available_offer`? From where this id should be get?

Comment: @Laerte I updated my question [ Add View ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, I think you have something like this:

```
@foreach ($requestedRoutes as $rr)
    <form action=".....">
        <tr>
            <td>{{$rr->date}}
            (...)
        </tr>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

You have to send the available_offersID to the Controller.
So, you could simply add a hidden field just after the form and set the id as the value, something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="available_offersID" value="{{ $rr->available_offersID }}">
```

Then, you can get the value in the Controller:

```
request('available_offersID')
```